# Node editor's backdrop and render result are not the same!

Tags: compositing-nodes

The backdrop:
[image]

Render result:
[image]

Output nodes are correctly connected. Not the same, tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the render layer not at the composite.
Change to composite here:

[image]